# Searching through arrays and Creating a custom array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function

I having an issue merging arrays. I have 3 arrays that show particular data. I need a way to search through all three arrays and if the record matches the date I need to store it in a new custom array.
I have 3 arrays that need to merge them using the date
The arrays are as follows.

```
// ARRAY 1
$transactions = array(
array(
   "date"=>"2021-03-01",
   "trans_count"=>100,
   "trans_amount"=>5300
),
array(
   "date"=>"2021-03-02",
   "trans_count"=>95,
   "trans_amount"=>5035
),
array(
   "date"=>"2021-03-03",
   "trans_count"=>105,
   "trans_amount"=>5565
)
);

// ARRAY 2
$overdrafts = array(
array(
   "date"=>"2021-03-01",
   "od_amount"=>500
),
array(
   "date"=>"2021-03-02",
   "od_amount"=>1000
),
);

// ARRAY 3
$payouts= array(
array(
   "date"=>"2021-03-02",
   "amount"=>2300
)
);
```

I tried to write a function but I got stuck. The end goal is to collect all records from all 3 arrays and coming up with one array.
the expected result should look like this.

```
$merged_arr = array(

   array(
       "date"=>"2021-03-01",
       "type"=>"transactions",
       "trans_count"=>100,
       "trans_amount"=>5300
    ),
   array(
       "date"=>"2021-03-01",
       "type"=>"overdrafts",
       "od_amount"=>500,
       
    ),

   array(
       "date"=>"2021-03-02",
       "type"=>"transactions",
       "trans_count"=>95,
       "trans_amount"=>5035
    ),
   array(
       "date"=>"2021-03-02",
       "type"=>"overdrafts",
       "od_amount"=>1000
    ),
   array(
       "date"=>"2021-03-02",
       "type"=>"payout",
       "od_amount"=>2300
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure of how to add the `type` for each of the different types automatically in a nice way, I'd suggest just adding the types directly on the initial arrays, or looping through each before merging them together.

As for the merging and sorting it's pretty easy and can be done with built-in functionality.

```php
$merged_arr = array_merge($transactions, $overdrafts, $payouts);

usort($merged_arr, function ($left, $right) {
    return new DateTime($left['date']) <=> new DateTime($right['date']);
});

// Demo merged array.
print "<pre>";

var_export($merged_arr);
```

The sort function will work with PHP 7 and up.